# Go prevent repetition

Tags: go, beego

I am working on web app that is going to have multple models (and related tables) and they are obviously going to have a lot of similiar methods, the only difference is going to be the returned result type.

Examples:

```
package models
type User struct {...}
type Task struct {...}

func GetUser(uid string) (*User, error) {
  user := User{Id: id}
  if err := ORM.Read(&user); err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  return &user, nil
}

func GetTask(uid string) (*Task, error) {
  task := Task{Id: id}
  if err := ORM.Read(&task); err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  return &task, nil
}
```

and many many more...

in Controllers etc I am using it like:

```
user := models.GetUser(id)
```

I am not really sure how to solve this problem in Golang, any suggestions?

PS: I am using [Beego Framework](https://beego.me/), if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the Model as an interface and expect the function to populate it. No need to return it. Basically you follow almost the exact paradigm that `ORM.Read` does.

```
// GetByID loads the model for dst's concrete type based on its Id field using ORM.Read
func GetByID(dst interface{}) error {
    if err := ORM.Read(dst); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return nil
}
```

This function expects you to create whatever model you are getting with the ID already set. It populates the model you pass in unless it returns an `error`.

So usage as follows:

```
user := User{Id: id}
err := GetByID(&user)
if err != nil {
    // handle error. model not populated
}
// user is ready to use

task := Task{Id: id}
err = GetByID(&task)
...
```

As a future note, when you run into this sort of situation again, take note of the function type of the library call you are making. Often times, if it takes an `interface{}` like this, you can easily make a generic wrapper by doing the exact same thing.